# Rosrun executable not found

Tags: ros, rosrun, fedora

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to run some code using *rosrun* on Fedora 19 (the same code works on Ubuntu). This is the error:

```
find: invalid mode ‘+111’
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named fitting below /home/andreas/catkin_ws/src/fitting
[rosrun] Found the following, but they're either not files,
[rosrun] or not executable:
[rosrun]   /home/andreas/catkin_ws/src/fitting
```

The executable is in /devel/lib, and echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH gives:

```
/home/andreas/catkin_ws/src:/home/andreas/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share:/home/andreas/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/stacks
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/68470/rosrun-executable-not-found/) by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 529 on 2013-07-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You say that the executable is in `/devel/lib` - I assume that you mean `/home/andreas/catkin_ws/devel/lib`? Are you manually setting the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH, or doing so by sourcing a catkin-generated setup file?

EDIT:

To address something that came up in the comments:
You shouldn't need to source both `~/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/setup.bash`  and `~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`. Assuming that you had sourced `~/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/setup.bash`  when you first created the catkin workspace as indicated in the [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace), in all subsequent terminals devel/setup.bash on its own is sufficient. See section 2.5 in the [conceptual overview](http://www.ros.org/wiki/catkin/conceptual_overview).

---

Originally posted by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) with karma: 1780 on 2013-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on 2013-07-24**:
You are right about the file path. I sourced catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash. So, ROS_PACKAGE_PATH needs to point to devel/lib?

**Comment by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) on 2013-07-24**:
No it does need to point to catkin_ws/src

**Comment by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on 2013-07-24**:
So, everything seems to be correct? Maybe I forgot to do sth in general ...

**Comment by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) on 2013-07-24**:
You did source both /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash and devel/setup.bash ? Can you do "ls -l" in fitting folder to check the rights you have and if you have the right to execute your programm. If you don't have them - it would be quite odd but not impossible - use chmod to set your file as executable.

**Comment by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on 2013-07-24**:
Yes, I sourced both of them, although the 1st one is: source ~/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/setup.bash (see http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Fedora#Building_the_catkin_Packages). ls -l within devel/lib/fitting gives: total 720
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 andreas andreas 734719 Jul 23 21:40 fitting

**Comment by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on 2013-07-24**:
I just redid the installation to /opt/ros/groovy according to: http://www.jann.cc/2013/04/29/building_ros_on_fedora_19.html. And I get the same error again.

**Comment by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) on 2013-07-24**:
You might want to put this information back in the original question, rather than a really long comment chain =) (I'd include the information about the exact original invocation of rosrun, full paths to all files, your path/what you're sourcing, and the steps you followed to set up your catkin_ws)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you trying to use a python file ? And if so, did you enable its execution ? If not using a python file, are you compiled your C++ code using catkin_make at the catkin's workspace root ?

---

Originally posted by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) with karma: 318 on 2013-07-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on 2013-07-24**:
No python. I compiled using catkin_make from /home/andreas/catkin_ws which should be the catkin's workspace root. I also sourced catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash